# JS-Data addAction method throws instead of rejecting the promise with the error message

Tags: javascript, axios, jsdata

In the js-data library, I have added a custom query with the `addAction()` method as shown [here](https://www.js-data.io/docs/reading-data). Now when my server returns a 4xx error code upon calling that custom action, an error is thrown but the server response (which is send) is nowhere to be found:

```
store.getMapper('school').getTeacherReports(1234, {
  basePath: 'reports'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('response', response.data)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err', err);
})
```

How should I handle this? Is there some method I don't know of that I should use? I already tried the `response` and `responseError` properties in the `addAction()` according to the [docs](http://api.js-data.io/js-data-http/3.0.0/module-js-data-http.html#-static-addAction__anchor).

Answer (score 1):

The `then` function can take two parameters:

```js
then(
  onSuccess: Function,
  onRejection: Function
)
```

So here is how you can handle the rejection due to the 4xx error:

```js
store.getMapper('school').getTeacherReports(1234, {
  basePath: 'reports'
}).then(
  function (response) { // on success
    console.log('response', response.data);
  },
  function (error) { // on error
    console.error(error);
  },
)
```

Comment: You are right, but then i don't understand why the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) says the `catch` _behaves the same_. Still my problem maintains js-data not passing my server response containing proper error messages about what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with axios: The rejected error object indeed has the response as a property ([source code](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/503418718f669fcc674719fd862b355605d7b41f/lib/core/settle.js)) but it doesn't appear as such in console outputs because error objects are shown differently in the console.
The following shows the underlying properties:

```
store.getMapper('school').getTeacherReports(1234, {
  basePath: 'reports'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('response', response.data)
}).catch(function(err) {
  let errorObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))
  console.log(errorObject)
});
```